# Typescript - update variable in arrow function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function like this:

```
private data: MyCustomDataObject;
private getData(): boolean {
    let val: boolean = true;   // variable declared
    this.service.callMethod().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        if (data == null) {
            val = false;   // val declared above is not updating
        } 
    });
return val; // this is still true, should be false
}
```

How come `val` isn't updating?

Comment: Where do you use `val`? (or `getData`)?

Comment: Is `subscribe` asynchronous? If so, `getData` is returning before the function you pass to `subscribe` ever runs

Comment: `getData` is called from another method in the same class, and `val` is used in that same method that calls `getData`

Comment: Judging by the naming scheme, the function you pass to `subscribe` is just a callback for when something changes. Am I right in guessing that?

Comment: @MichaelHulet Yes that's right

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that `subscribe` takes the function you give it, and hangs onto it for later, when some event happens. It doesn't actually run your function when you pass it. Because of this, the `getData` function moves on without your callback ever being called, so the value of `val` never changes before `getData` returns. If you want it to return `false`, you'll need to change `val` outside of the callback that you pass to `subscribe`.